# QGIS How to multiply (repeat n times) a point by field

Tags: qgis, geoprocessing

I have a point layer in QGIS that has a field named "Amount" that stores an integer value for every point in the layer.

I want to create N points in the exact place of the feature that has N as value in the amount "field". I mean, if a point has in the amount field 16, I need to create 15 more points in that exact lat long (1+15 so that there are 16 in total) of that point.

After this process, the sum of "Amount" values in the starting layer should be equal to the sum of points in the new layer.

I need it to create a heatmap with the new layer. What is the easyest way of achiving this?

Regards

Comment: Rather than creating a bunch of duplicate points, why not use that field as a weight in the heatmap creation?

Comment: i didn't know that that was possible @Chris W, where is that option?

Comment: If you're using the Heatmap Plugin, check the Advanced box and that should activate the lower half of the dialog, where there is another box called Use weight from field to check and then select the appropriate field in the dropdown next to it. See http://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_heatmap.html?highlight=heatmap Figure 2.

Comment: thanks man! can you please write that on an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Technically it doesn't answer the question (duplicating points) - it's just because you stated *why* you wanted to do so I could suggest something else that you didn't need to. I'd also make sure to test the idea and ensure it does what you want.